# Android - To check if the phone has a network provider

Tags: android

I have an android app, in that there is a particular requirement where in I need to check if the Android device has a network provider or its just WiFi enabled.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
     //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
final NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
int type = networkInfo.getType();
String typeName = networkInfo.getTypeName();
boolean connected = networkInfo.isConnected()
```

- `networkInfo.getType()` will return `0` when connected to **Mobile**
  network or `1` when connected trough **WIFI**.
- `networkInfo.getTypeName()`
  will return the strings `mobile` or `WIFI`.
- `networkInfo.isConnected()`
  will tell you whether or not you have an active connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29).

`isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` is what you need

Comment: Actually,I wanted to check if the phone has EDGE/GPRS/3G .