# Android is there an exception for no mobile signal?

Tags: android, network-protocols

My app sends SMS messages, I was wondering if there's an exception to catch in case theres no mobile network (signal reception) available and the SMS cannot be sent?

Comment: Nice question! [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211081/android-to-check-if-the-phone-has-a-network-provider?lq=1) for the "normal" way of checking if the mobile network is available. As I looked up the API documentation for `telephony.SmsManager`, the `sendTextMessage` method will only throw an Exception if there are illegal arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that calling `SmsManager.sendTextMessage()` doesn't immediately and synchronously send the message, so this will not throw an exception due to failure to send.

However, when you call `sendTextMessage()` you can provide a `PendingIntent` that will be triggered upon success/failure of the sending of the message. Here's the relevant part of the documentation for that parameter:

> if not null, an ArrayList of PendingIntents (one for each message
>   part) that is broadcast when the corresponding message part has been
>   sent. The result code will be Activity.RESULT_OK for success, or one
>   of these errors:
>
> RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE
>
> RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
>
> RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU
>
> For RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE each sentIntent may include the extra
>   "errorCode" containing a radio technology specific value, generally
>   only useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exception AFAIK but you can use [ConnectivityManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to get information like this.

You will need `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission as well.